# Global variables in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two main scripts for my pyQT5 gui. First the GUI file ("MSCVgui_script") then the run file ("guiRun".py). I when I run my run file the GUI crashes when I modify the variable "self.imageFiles1" in the funciton assingPics.

What I do:

1. run "guiRun.py"
2. Select "Browse File"
3. select folder from the pop up
4. Close pop up
5. select the check mark blue on the GUI
6. Crash-> no error report 
   The photo file paths are"C:\Users.....\Images\photo_Blue.jpg"
   names are "photo_Blue"

runGui script below

```
from MSCVgui_script import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import glob
import cv2
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import fileExplorer

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):




  def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setupInputs()
    #List of image types 
    self.image_Types=["photo_NIR", "photo_UV", "photo_Unfiltered", "photo_Polarized","photo_DarkRed","photo_LightRed","photo_Orange","photo_LightGreen","photo_Cyan","photo_Blue"]

    #first stack of images 
    self.imageFiles1 = {}
    #images to process 
    self.images_to_process=[]


  def setupInputs(self):
    self.File01.clicked.connect(self.openFolder)
    self.checkBox_BL.stateChanged.connect(self.imageChange)
    #self.checkBox_UV.clicked.connect(self.image1Change()
    #self.checkBox_NIR.clicked.toggle.onnect(self.image1Change(0))




  #open folder and import images into code
  def assingPics(self,folder):
    path = folder+"/*.jpg"
    image_files = glob.glob(path)
    for filepath in image_files:
      for i in self.image_Types:
        if(i in filepath):
          #self.imageFiles1[i] = filepath#HERE SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM 
          break
    print("done")


  #open the folder containing the images to build a stack from 
  def openFolder(self):
    folderOpener = fileExplorer.App()
    imgFiles = folderOpener.openFileNameDialog()
    folderOpener.closeTh()
    self.assingPics(imgFiles)
    return imgFiles

  #change image 1 according to check box
  def imageChange(self):
    print("CHANGE")
    if(self.checkBox_BL.isChecked()):
      print("start")
      imag = self.imageFiles1['photo_Blue']
      imag = cv2.imread(imag,0)
      imag = QtGui.QImage(imag.data, imag.shape[1], imag.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
    if(self.checkBox_CY.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_DR.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")


    if(self.checkBox_LG.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")


    if(self.checkBox_LP.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_LR.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_NIR.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_OR.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_UF.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")

    if(self.checkBox_UV.isChecked()):
      print("dumb")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook 
    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
      print(exctype, value, traceback)
      sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback) 
      sys.exit(1) 
      sys.excepthook = exception_hook 
    # from multiprocessing import freeze_support
    # freeze_support()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    # icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    # icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exe/xrt.ico"),QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    # window.setWindowIcon(icon)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

MSCVgui_script below

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1640, 900)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.File01 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.File01.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 5, 200, 40))
        self.File01.setObjectName("File01")
        self.Image01 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Image01.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 85, 1000, 300))
        self.Image01.setObjectName("Image01")
        self.checkBox_UV = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_UV.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 45, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_UV.setObjectName("checkBox_UV")
        self.checkBox_NIR = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_NIR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 45, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_NIR.setObjectName("checkBox_NIR")
        self.checkBox_DR = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_DR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 45, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_DR.setObjectName("checkBox_DR")
        self.checkBox_LR = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 45, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_LR.setObjectName("checkBox_LR")
        self.checkBox_OR = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_OR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 45, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_OR.setObjectName("checkBox_OR")
        self.checkBox_LG = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LG.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 405, 97, 20))
        self.checkBox_LG.setObjectName("checkBox_LG")
        self.checkBox_CY = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_CY.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 405, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_CY.setObjectName("checkBox_CY")
        self.checkBox_BL = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_BL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 405, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_BL.setObjectName("checkBox_BL")
        self.checkBox_LP = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 405, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_LP.setObjectName("checkBox_LP")
        self.checkBox_UF = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_UF.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 405, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_UF.setObjectName("checkBox_UF")
        self.File02 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.File02.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 440, 200, 40))
        self.File02.setObjectName("File02")
        self.Image02 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Image02.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 515, 1000, 300))
        self.Image02.setObjectName("Image02")
        self.checkBox_UV2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_UV2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 480, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_UV2.setObjectName("checkBox_UV2")
        self.checkBox_NIR2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_NIR2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 480, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_NIR2.setObjectName("checkBox_NIR2")
        self.checkBox_DR2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_DR2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 480, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_DR2.setObjectName("checkBox_DR2")
        self.checkBox_LR2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LR2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 480, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_LR2.setObjectName("checkBox_LR2")
        self.checkBox_OR2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_OR2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 480, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_OR2.setObjectName("checkBox_OR2")
        self.checkBox_LG2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LG2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 830, 97, 20))
        self.checkBox_LG2.setObjectName("checkBox_LG2")
        self.checkBox_CY2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_CY2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 830, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_CY2.setObjectName("checkBox_CY2")
        self.checkBox_BL2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_BL2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 830, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_BL2.setObjectName("checkBox_BL2")
        self.checkBox_LP2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_LP2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 830, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_LP2.setObjectName("checkBox_LP2")
        self.checkBox_UF2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_UF2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 830, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox_UF2.setObjectName("checkBox_UF2")
        self.line_vert = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_vert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1050, 30, 20, 801))
        self.line_vert.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_vert.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_vert.setObjectName("line_vert")
        self.ImageAnalysisHeading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ImageAnalysisHeading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1190, 20, 329, 22))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.ImageAnalysisHeading.setFont(font)
        self.ImageAnalysisHeading.setObjectName("ImageAnalysisHeading")
        self.radioButton_ImageDif = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_ImageDif.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 670, 141, 20))
        self.radioButton_ImageDif.setObjectName("radioButton_ImageDif")
        self.radioButton_Otsu = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_Otsu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 120, 211, 20))
        self.radioButton_Otsu.setObjectName("radioButton_Otsu")
        self.label_EdgeDetHeading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_EdgeDetHeading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 180, 111, 16))
        self.label_EdgeDetHeading.setObjectName("label_EdgeDetHeading")
        self.radioButton_Canny = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_Canny.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 220, 161, 20))
        self.radioButton_Canny.setObjectName("radioButton_Canny")
        self.radioButton_laplacian = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_laplacian.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1320, 220, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_laplacian.setObjectName("radioButton_laplacian")
        self.radioButton_sobelx = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_sobelx.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 260, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_sobelx.setObjectName("radioButton_sobelx")
        self.radioButton_sobely = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_sobely.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1320, 260, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_sobely.setObjectName("radioButton_sobely")
        self.radioButton_XRcustum = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_XRcustum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 630, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_XRcustum.setObjectName("radioButton_XRcustum")
        self.radioButton_plotH = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_plotH.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 710, 121, 20))
        self.radioButton_plotH.setObjectName("radioButton_plotH")
        self.radioButton_CLAHE = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_CLAHE.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1530, 320, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_CLAHE.setObjectName("radioButton_CLAHE")
        self.radioButton_Watershed = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_Watershed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 320, 221, 20))
        self.radioButton_Watershed.setObjectName("radioButton_Watershed")
        self.radioButton_contours = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_contours.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1320, 320, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_contours.setObjectName("radioButton_contours")
        self.label_MorphHeading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_MorphHeading.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 380, 191, 16))
        self.label_MorphHeading.setObjectName("label_MorphHeading")
        self.radioButton_erosion = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_erosion.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 410, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_erosion.setObjectName("radioButton_erosion")
        self.radioButton_dilation = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_dilation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1320, 410, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_dilation.setObjectName("radioButton_dilation")
        self.radioButton_closing = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_closing.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1530, 410, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_closing.setObjectName("radioButton_closing")
        self.radioButton_opening = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_opening.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 450, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton_opening.setObjectName("radioButton_opening")
        self.radioButton_morphgradient = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_morphgradient.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1320, 450, 171, 20))
        self.radioButton_morphgradient.setObjectName("radioButton_morphgradient")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1200, 760, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(27, 425, 1001, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1200, 510, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 80, 131, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 590, 131, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1640, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision.setFont(font)
        self.menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision.setObjectName("menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.File01.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse File (Image 1)"))
        self.Image01.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Image01"))
        self.checkBox_UV.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "UV"))
        self.checkBox_NIR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NIR"))
        self.checkBox_DR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dark Red"))
        self.checkBox_LR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Light Red"))
        self.checkBox_OR.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Orange"))
        self.checkBox_LG.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Light Green"))
        self.checkBox_CY.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cyan"))
        self.checkBox_BL.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blue"))
        self.checkBox_LP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Polarized"))
        self.checkBox_UF.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unfiltered"))
        self.File02.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse File (Image 2)"))
        self.Image02.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Image02"))
        self.checkBox_UV2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "UV"))
        self.checkBox_NIR2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NIR"))
        self.checkBox_DR2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dark Red"))
        self.checkBox_LR2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Light Red"))
        self.checkBox_OR2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Orange"))
        self.checkBox_LG2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Light Green"))
        self.checkBox_CY2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cyan"))
        self.checkBox_BL2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Blue"))
        self.checkBox_LP2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Polarized"))
        self.checkBox_UF2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unfiltered"))
        self.ImageAnalysisHeading.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SELECT IMAGE ANALYSIS TO PERFORM"))
        self.radioButton_ImageDif.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Image Difference"))
        self.radioButton_Otsu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Binarization (Otsu Threshold)"))
        self.label_EdgeDetHeading.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edge Detection"))
        self.radioButton_Canny.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canny Edge Detection"))
        self.radioButton_laplacian.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Laplacian"))
        self.radioButton_sobelx.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sobel X"))
        self.radioButton_sobely.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sobel Y"))
        self.radioButton_XRcustum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "XR Custom"))
        self.radioButton_plotH.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plot Histogram"))
        self.radioButton_CLAHE.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLAHE"))
        self.radioButton_Watershed.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Watershed Image Segmentation"))
        self.radioButton_contours.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Contours"))
        self.label_MorphHeading.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Morphological Transformations"))
        self.radioButton_erosion.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Erosion"))
        self.radioButton_dilation.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dilation"))
        self.radioButton_closing.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Closing"))
        self.radioButton_opening.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Opening"))
        self.radioButton_morphgradient.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Morphological Gradient"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RUN & SAVE"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE OUTPUT"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PREPROCESSING"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IMAGE ANALYSIS"))
        self.menuMulti_Spectrum_Computer_Vision.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Multi-Spectrum Computer Vision"))
```

I know it is something to do with the self.imageFiles1[i] class variable and my lack of understanding of pyQT5. Can someone elaborate how to treat global variables in a pyQT5 run script?

Comment: You have republished the same question but you still do not provide what I have asked you: Show the name of the .jpg files in the folder you select. And why the need to create a new account?

Comment: I wanted to start fresh with a new post but it wouldn't let me re post. "C:\Users.............\GUImscv\Images\photo_DarkRed.jpg" this is the file

Comment: 1) It is that you should not publish again but only edit your initial question with the requested information, so the system repeats it for users to review. 2) Is there only photo_DarkRed.jpg? If so, then explain the error since you must throw the error since in `self.imageFiles1['photo_Blue']` it will `photo_Blue` not exist in `self.imageFiles1`.

Comment: No there is a set of images, I should have used the blue image as the reference in my first comment. "C:\Users\......Images\photo_Blue.jpg" does exist. That error where self.imageFiles1['photo_Blue']  is , is not the problem. The gui doesn't get to part of the code before crashing. It crashes right when self.checkBox_BL.stateChanged.connect(self.imageChange) is called

Comment: That's why I ask you to tell me only the names of those images, I don't want the path just the name. Can you provide what I've asked for?

Comment: name of the image in quesiton is "photo_Blue"

Comment: These are the names of this images: ["photo_NIR", "photo_UV", "photo_Unfiltered", "photo_Polarized","photo_DarkRed","photo_LightRed","photo_Orange","photo_LightGreen","photo_Cyan","photo_Blue"] I am sorry I am confused on exactly what you are asking for, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imag = cv2.imread(imag, 0)` returns a greyscale image so `imag.data` will be an ndarray containing `height*width` 8-bit integers instead of `height*width*3` which is what is needed for `QtGui.QImage(imag.data, imag.shape[1], imag.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)`. To load a color image use `imag = cv2.imread(imag, 1)` (or simply `imag = cv2.imread(imag)` since `flag == 1` is the default).

As an alternative you could just use the file name to initialize the `QImage` object instead of constructing an `OpenCV` image first.

```
imag = QtGui.QImage(self.imageFiles1['photo_Blue'])
```